# Return float st(0) or xmm0

Tags: c++, visual-studio, x86, calling-convention, x87

Directive for determining in which register (`st(0)` or `xmm0`) the floating point value from the assembler block in C++ code will be returned.

```
__declspec(naked) float __fastcall ln(float flt)
{
    float buf;

    _asm {
        mov buf, eax
        fld buf             // Return st(0)
    };
};
```

Comment: So what's the question? What do you want? This is just words with no context or real meaning. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question

Comment: Unless your code is targeted towards the most generic i386 processor without SSE support, compilers will prefer to the \*MM registers over the i387 stack.

Comment: Sorry. English is not my native language.
There is a C ++ program code, inside the C ++ code there is an assembly block that calculates the natural logarithm of a number, when compiling the visual studio program code, in some cases, the program expects the result of the assembler code in register st (0) in others in register xmm0. how to tell the visual studio that the assembler insert returns the result in the xmm0 register?

Comment: Edit the question with your code (and maybe resulting glue assembly)

Comment: Edit your question, don't put an external link in. Shorten the code if you must.

Answer (score 3):

For 32-bit x86 code, Visual studio will [always use the i387 stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/floating-point-coprocessor-and-calling-conventions?view=vs-2019), as it is the calling convention.
For 64-bit x64 code, the XMM registers are used [exclusively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019).

I'm afraid you have no choice but to write separate asm blocks for different architectures. If only you had a higher-level language that generated specific assembly code for each architecture it supports ... ;)

Comment: I use the /arch:SSE2 key, but the visual studio still creates a code in which, when exiting the assembly block, the result is saved from the register st (0).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pfP5SMDAxgnsjuRJo0UV2o8Z12eYKGMV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: when compiling on one computer, the C ++ code waits for the result in st (0), when compiling on another computer, the c ++ code waits for the result in the register xmm0

Comment: Did you make sure you're using the same compiler version, compiler options, and the same target platform?

Comment: I made sure that different versions do it differently, and now I'm trying to find which key is responsible for this.

Comment: The only "responsible key" is your target architecture (x86 or x64)